# Unable to remove 'thumbnails.fraghandler' from bin

Tags: terminal, finder, trash

I'm running MacOS Mojave.

For months, I have the following file in my bin which I'm unable to remove:

`~/.Trash/Recovered files #1/(A Document Being Saved By Quick Look Helper)/thumbnails.fraghandler`

Stuff I've tried:

`sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files\ \#1/`(operation not permitted)

`chflags uchg thumbnails.fraghandler`(operation not permitted)

chmod the directory (operation not permitted)

I can move the file to another folder (e.g. Desktop), but unable to remove it from there as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of macOS.  Saying "the latest macOS" isn't helpful because different Macs can run different versions at different times.

Comment: @Faun88, See my answer in the linked possible duplicate and adjust the path and file name as appropriate.

Comment: See this SuperUser question for some tips: https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x/518545